# How to find history of commands run on mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I sort of have a heart attack of a problem.  I had a non-root utility user in mysql that used to be able to see all the databases, tables, etc. on the mysql instance.  The user was also able to insert records, delete records, create tables, etc. too.  This user is used by scripts to edit records, or view the data as someone who's not root via phpmyadmin.

I don't know how Django fits into this or if it was even the cause but a contractor needed access to the db to work on their project we asked them to work on.  They said they were using Django and needed to create some auth tables in the database (auth_group, auth_user, auth_user_groups, etc.)

However, after they added their tables for Django, that utility user can't see anything except the "information_schema" database.

Luckily, I checked using the root user in mysql and can see the databases but somehow, I still cant see the databases with the non-root user.  I don't see anything that jumps out at me permissions-wise in the "user" table in mysql so I'm not sure how to fix this problem.  I want to see what commands the contractor ran to get us into this situation to tell them not to do this again.

I was going to check the .mysql_history file in the unix root user directory but the funny thing is the file is dated from 3 weeks ago so it doesn't look like this will yield any info on what was run.

So, back to my original question, where can I see a history of mysql commands that were run on mysql so I can figure out what happened or what was run to get us into this funny situation?

Comment: I suspect the contractor is not logged in using the utility user. If they log in without specifying any user, they may be logged in as a default user mysteriously named 'odbc' or else named the same as their linux username. But with no privileges. You can check by asking them to run `SHOW GRANTS;` in the mysql client.

Comment: I suggest you ask them to edit a `~/.my.cnf` in their home directory to set the correct user and password, so they don't forget.

Comment: Sorry for your situation.  I would suggest asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, as this isn't really a DRF question, or even django.  This is down to mysql query logging.

Comment: Moderator, can someone migrate this question over to dba.stackexchange.com please?  If I can do it myself, can someone point me to the instructions on how to do it?  I can't seem to figure out how to migrate this over.

Comment: *where can I see a history of mysql commands that were run on mysql so I can figure out what happened or what was run to get us into this funny situation?* In general in MySQL there exists the only place where all queries are logged, and it is the [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html). But in most cases this kind of logging is disabled. If so then you'd search does OS or an application have its own logging.